# NamedTuples, Hashable and Python

Tags: python, namedtuple, hashable, typed

Consider the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

from typing import NamedTuple, Set

class Person(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    fred: Set[str]


p = Person("Phil", set())
print(p)

my_dict = {}
my_dict[p] = 10


print(my_dict)
```

which produces this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./temp.py", line 14, in <module>
    my_dict[p] = 10
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

In this case, it's sample code, and I have simplified it lots, so its
quite easy to see where the error comes from. `typed.NamedTuple`
obviousl calculates its hash based on all of its instances variables
and one of them is a set. When I discovered this, however, it was
painful to track down.

So, my question is, why is the error message showing this? Should it
not be `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Person'`. And why is the
traceback not coming from the bowels of python somewhere where the
error actually is.

Comment: Well, that *is* the error that is being produced in the bowels of Python, it is trying to hash a `set` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NamedTuple` is based on the `tuple` class. See [`collections.namedtuple()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L464)

The hash of a `tuple` is the combined hash of all the elements. See [`tupleobject.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Objects/tupleobject.c#L336-L369)

Since `set` is unhashable it is not possible to hash a `tuple` or `NamedTuple` containing a `set`.

And since the hashing of a set is implemented in C you don't see the traceback

Comment: Yes, I see that. I think the `HashNotImplemented` call is happening too deep. It should be reporting either the outer object type, or the both ("Person is not hashable, because it contains a set which is not hashable").